# How to troubleshoot "out of memory" errors in a VB6 application

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vb6

I have be charged with finding out whty one of the legacy applications crashes after performing a function several times. I downloaded a profiler tool "Glowcode" and ran the application through it. It reported many leaks and I eventually got the stack information for them. But what to do now?

I was surfing around and found a tutorial creating a "map document" at compile time that links memory adress to specific lines of code. The tutorial was for a later version of Visual Studio and I couldnt find  the same settings in VB6..

SO to summarize if someone could direct me to a step by step tutorial or advise me that would be great.

Comment: Remember that the VB6 IDE is COMPLETELY different to visual studio. Many things that apply in VS just don't exist or have any comparison in VB6.  
Having said that, if you tell VB6 to create symbolic debug info when it compile, you may get a more meaningful call stack for your leaked memory.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the objects after you used them, avoid cross references.

Here is a useful article on the topic: http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=106

Comment: yes I went through the code and closed whatever i could see but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have cross references or external calls?

Comment: Probably - I managed to get a pdb file with some help by loading the project in VS2008. I found 3 leaks and narrowed them down to 3 procedures but cant seem to see any issues.

Comment: Post the procedures, we will take a look.